# Pip: How to override version of sub-dependency in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, conda, apple-m1

I recently switched to Apple Silicon and am trying to now install all packages in a Python project in the `requirements.txt`. However, since the architecture is different, I have trouble satisfying all requirements, specifically sub-dependencies.

*requirements.txt*

```
ethnicolr==0.8.1
# and many more, but this one is causing issues
```

Installing it with `pip install -r requirements.txt` yields

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> tensorflow==2.5.2 (from ethnicolr) (from versions: none)

TensorFlow 2.4.0 is available for this setup, and it should work with ethnicolr. So how do I override the version of the sub-dependency in `requirements.txt`?

I am using Mambaforge for virtual environments btw. because it is [recommended](https://coiled.io/blog/apple-arm64-mambaforge/) to run a PyData Stack on Apple M1

Answer (score 3):

A way to workaround that is to explicitly set your dependencies and run `pip install` with a `--no-deps` parameter.

After setting my `requirements.txt` as:

```
ethnicolr==0.8.1
# and many more, but this one is causing issues
tensorflow==2.5.0 # You set this to whatever version you want to
```

I ran:

```sh
> pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt                                                                                      
Collecting ethnicolr==0.8.1
  Using cached ethnicolr-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36.1 MB)
Collecting tensorflow==2.5.0
  Using cached tensorflow-2.5.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (454.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow, ethnicolr
Successfully installed ethnicolr-0.8.1 tensorflow-2.5.0
```

This implies a clear issue: You'll have to know beforehand which deps your packages use. To easily find out those, you can use [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools)

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that Tensorflow 2.5.2 is not available for the M1 chip. Tensorflow 2.5.0 is, but it is causing issues with ethnicolr. I think there is no easy fix and I raised an issue in the ethnicolr repo.

Comment: You may try 2.6.0

Answer (score 0):

You should install a version of ethnicolr that doesn't have that specific requirement for the tensorflow version. `pip install ethnicolr==0.2.0`could work.

Comment: Thanks. But my min requirement is ethnicolr==0.4.0. Any other way to override the version? The readme for the current version of ethnicolr says that tensorflow 2.x works

Comment: Ethnicolr is very specific: https://github.com/appeler/ethnicolr/blob/master/requirements.txt says 2.5.2.

Comment: Sorry @Ola, there doesn't seem to be any good way around this. Without knowing how exactly Ethnicolr is implemented, one has to assume that the requirement for 2.5.2 is there for a good reason. You should only use the ```--no-deps``` switch if you can tolerate that your application sometimes breaks in unpredictable ways.

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to install Tensorflow 2.5.0 on my M1 machine and it is kind of running. But some functions fail. I raised an issue in the ethnicolr repo. This is the guide to install Tensorflow 2.5.0 on m1: https://medium.com/@theDrewDag/how-to-install-tensorflow-2-5-on-apple-m1-7c42cf51af95

Answer (score 0):

In `conda` I can have the following `environment.yml`:

```yaml
# name of the environment
name: rust_env
# channels from which the dependencies will be sourced. The order defines the priority.
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
# conda dependencies
dependencies:
  # name==version==hash?
  - anyio=3.3.4=py39hcbf5309_1
  # ...
  - pip:
    # regular pip dependency
    # name==version
    - jupyter-contrib-core==0.3.3
    # dependency sourced from git repo
    # name@git+link
    - nbconvert@git+https://github.com/JohnScience/nbconvert.git@0b84bb8c3d94cfa229d12c1069e426d907e98d05
```